# Include .pro file in another .pro file

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm trying to build some projects with QtCreator.

And there's a lot of code in common between the two .pro files.

Is there any mean to make the two .pro files call another unique .pro file that contains the common informations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#include-filename). You can just write:

```
include(otherproject.pro)
```

And not duplicating code is always a good idea.

Comment: Is there a way to have the pathes in `otherproject.pro` be treated as relative to `otherproject.pro`?